# Where to find patient responses on Rorschach's Inkblot test?

Tags: data, artificial-intelligence, mental-illness

I am looking to find data that has patient's responses to Rorschach's inblots as well and their associated diagnosis ( Mainly looking into patients that have been diagnosed with schizophrenia, depression or a related mental illness).
I have been able to find researches that mention they have used a number of patients, and give out their Exner scoring system for their illness, but is there a place where I can find the actual responses?
I do not need confidential data, mainly just patient's responses. Looking into doing some experimentative AI related tasks.

Where would I find such data?
Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have links to the research using the Exner scoring system please?

Comment: Sure. One of them -> https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Some-Rorschach-data-comparing-schizophrenics-with-Exner/3e22f119bb16b73ae1811405395f484efcd8511a#extracted

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Exner scoring seems to be the standard for Rorschach test studies. The scores are likely a way of protecting patients that may give very personal answers that can identify them. For example, if a research subject reports the Rorschach image as reminding them of their hometown in Brooklyn and their mother who is a famous person, a research study that report raw data and raw responses will not pass ethics due to confidentiality issues.

You are right, most studies use the Exner reporting system -

[Japanese study looking at young people with schizophrenia](https://www.dovepress.com/distinctive-rorschach-profiles-of-young-adults-with-schizophrenia-and--peer-reviewed-fulltext-article-NDT)

[Adolescent females study](https://www.uccs.edu/samuelsonlab/sites/samuelsonlab/files/inline-files/franklin%20and%20cornell%201997.pdf)

You will likely need to contact studies and join teams that do Rorschach studies to learn the specifics for yourself. Unfortunately, you would not be able to cite or use it as the basis for your research.

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. My background is purely cs, so I did not fully understand the sensitivity of such descriptions. Thank you!